# Adding documentation on GitHub projects with appledoc

Tags: github, appledoc

I've noticed some projects on GitHub have documentation pages created with Appledoc and hosted at username.github.com/project/Documentation. For example:

Project: http://pandamonia.github.com/BlocksKit/
Documentation: http://pandamonia.github.com/BlocksKit/Documentation/

How does this work? Is there a way I could do this for my own project?

Answer (score 0):

Github has the concept of project pages - see this page for details:

http://pages.github.com/

You can see the contents of the web pages on the gh-pages branch of the project:

https://github.com/pandamonia/BlocksKit/tree/gh-pages